# List categories of top level parent of current category - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to list the categories of the top level parent of a current category in Wordpres. This is the code I have the at the moment:

```
$currentcat = get_query_var('cat');
$cats_str = get_category_parents($cat, false, '%#%');
$cats_array = explode('%#%', $cats_str);
$cat_depth = sizeof($cats_array)-2;

<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of='.$currentcat); ?>
```

However this only list the categories of the current category, I want to show all categories underneath the top level of the current category. Thanks

Comment: So you want to display all the subcategories of the current category?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$term =  $wp_query->queried_object;
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = 'your_taxonomy';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
   $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
   echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name .   '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```